# CLion inconsistent auto indentation for line comment

Tags: c++, ide, clion, jetbrains-ide

There are some weird auto indentation going on in CLion that I don't understand why. Here is an example

```
int i1(5); // some comments, then I hit Enter
// auto indentation goes here. I hit Enter again
// It goes here
float f = 5; // some comments, then I hit Enter
    // then auto indentation goes here. I hit Enter again
        // It then goes here.
float f2 = 6;
// If I don't comment on the previous line, there is no weird indentation
```

It seems like whenever I use = to initialize an variable, and then add comment at the end of the line, it will give me extra indentation on the next line. But in all other instance, it will not give me extra indentation.

I recently installed CLion and it was using default code style. It seems like the the extra indentation is controlled by the continuation indent setting, but I only want this continuation indent setting be application to codes, not comments. Where can I change me setting to disable the continuation indentation for comment when using = for assignment?

Comment: Isn't clion using clang-format? Or does such indentation only happen when you type?

Comment: It should not be so hard to find the code-style settings, if you look around a little in your menus. As for the indentation itself, it seems like a possible bug which should be reported to [the CLion issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP).

Comment: @VTT  The extra indentation only happen when I type. When I selected that block and clicked auto indent lines again, CLion actually knows the extra indentation is not correct and remove it.

Comment: I will be fixed in next CLion 2018.2 EAP.

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been fixed in CLion 2018.2 EAP (https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/nextversion/ ).

I personally uninstalled CLion 2018.1 because of this bug, since the EAP was stable enough.