# How to stop CLion from double indenting after comments?

Tags: intellij-idea, clion

In CLion, whenever I start a line with a comment, the next line is always double indented. I cannot find any style rules that fit this.

Example:

```
// One line comment
        < Cursor is here after pressing <Enter>
```

This behavior is not happening in any of my other IntelliJ IDEs.

I'm not sure if this is the same bug described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50204073/clion-inconsistent-auto-indentation-for-line-comment), as the poster there did not have the same issue, the weird indentation happened after a statement, not just a comment. I am running 2018.1.3, so I could try updating, but I usually like to stick to the stable releases.

Answer (score 2):

This has been tracked in the issue tracker of JetBrains at [CPP-12912](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-12912), and `In Progress` of [CPP-12350](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-12350), and the author of CPP-12912 seems asked a question at StackOverflow as you said.

In this issue, a member of AppCode developer said using CLion 2018.2 seems solve it.

For something funny: This indentation bug cannot be repeated at the Code Style page in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if this IS a CLion defect and updating may help. See Q & A here:
[CLion inconsistent auto indentation for line comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50204073/clion-inconsistent-auto-indentation-for-line-comment)